# Hide div element after a few seconds Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I am having trouble understanding how to do this and how to approach this issue... I have a scroll animation on my page and I want to hide that div with animation after 3 seconds when it comes into view.

My HTML code for animated element is:

```
<div class="scroll-animation-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-animation">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code in my Typescript is:

```
hideAnimatedDiv() {
        const animatedDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-animation');
        this.animatedDiv = true;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('hide');
            this.animatedDiv = false;
        }, 3000);
    }
```

**I keep getting this error:**

```
ERROR in src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(577,14): error TS2339: Property 'animatedDiv' does not exist on type 'ConfiguratorComponent'.
src/app/configurator/configurator.component.ts(580,18): error TS2339: Property 'animatedDiv' does not exist on type 'ConfiguratorComponent'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to find `animatedDiv` property as global, because you have used `this.animatedDiv` instead try like this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="scroll-animation-wrapper">
  <div id="scroll-animation" class="scroll-animation">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.hideAnimatedDiv()
}

hideAnimatedDiv() {
   let animatedDiv = document.getElementById('scroll-animation');
   animatedDiv.style.display = 'block';
   setTimeout(() => {
     console.log('hide');
     animatedDiv.style.display = 'none';
   }, 3000);
}
```

To hide any element, we need to use `style.display` property of that element, like shown in the code.

**Note**: I have used `ngOnInit` function to make sure that `div` is hidden after component load only.

Comment: Your approach results in cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') angular because the div isn't loaded yet.. How do I wait for it or check if it exist already?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide div I would suggest you this:

```
<div class="scroll-animation-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll-animation" *ngIf="isDisplayed">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I added " *ngIf="isDisplayed" ". You should add the property "isDisplayed" to the component.

```
public isDisplayed: boolean = true;

hideAnimatedDiv() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.isDisplayed = false;
    }, 3000);
}
```

If you want to add animation in Angular, the best way is to implement it as [Angular Team suggests](https://angular.io/guide/animations):

With this specific case I would use ":enter" ":leave" approach:  https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#use-of-ngif-and-ngfor-with-enter-and-leave

Comment: This seems like a good way, but I want the timeout to start after i reach the page that this div is located... now it happens instantly right after the app is loaded